# Is this an optimization bug in g++?

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, g++

I'm not sure whether I've found a bug in g++ (4.4.1-4ubuntu9), or if I'm doing
something wrong. What I believe I'm seeing is a bug introduced by enabling
optimization with g++ -O2. I've tried to distill the code down to just the
relevant parts.

When optimization is enabled, I have an ASSERT which is failing. When
optimization is disabled, the same ASSERT does not fail. I think I've tracked
it down to the optimization of one function and its callers.

### The System

- Language: C++
- Ubuntu 9.10
- g++-4.4.real (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9) 4.4.1
- Linux 2.6.31-22-server x86_64

### Optimization Enabled

Object compiled with:
`g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -fPIC -g -O2  -MT file.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/file.Tpo -c -o file.o file.cpp`

And here is the relevant code from `objdump -dg file.o`.

```
00000000000018b0 <helper_function>:
;; This function takes two parameters:
;; pointer to int: %rdi
;; pointer to int[]: %rsi
    18b0:       0f b6 07                movzbl (%rdi),%eax
    18b3:       83 f8 12                cmp    $0x12,%eax
    18b6:       74 60                   je     1918 <helper_function+0x68>
    18b8:       83 f8 17                cmp    $0x17,%eax
    18bb:       74 5b                   je     1918 <helper_function+0x68>
...
    1918:       c7 06 32 00 00 00       movl   $0x32,(%rsi)
    191e:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
    1920:       c3                      retq  
    
0000000000005290 <buggy_invoker>:
... snip ...
    52a0:       48 81 ec c8 01 00 00    sub    $0x1c8,%rsp
    52a7:       48 8d 84 24 a0 01 00    lea    0x1a0(%rsp),%rax
    52ae:       00 
    52af:       48 c7 84 24 a0 01 00    movq   $0x0,0x1a0(%rsp)
    52b6:       00 00 00 00 00 
    52bb:       48 c7 84 24 a8 01 00    movq   $0x0,0x1a8(%rsp)
    52c2:       00 00 00 00 00 
    52c7:       c7 84 24 b0 01 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x1b0(%rsp)
    52ce:       00 00 00 00 
    52d2:       4c 8d 7c 24 20          lea    0x20(%rsp),%r15
    52d7:       48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
    52da:       48 89 44 24 08          mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
;; ***** BUG HERE *****
;; Pointer to int[] loaded into %rsi
;; But where is %rdi populated?
    52df:       e8 cc c5 ff ff          callq  18b0 <helper_function>

0000000000005494 <perfectly_fine_invoker>:
    5494:       48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
    5498:       0f ae f0                mfence 
    549b:       48 8d 7c 24 30          lea    0x30(%rsp),%rdi
    54a0:       48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
    54a3:       48 c7 04 24 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,(%rsp)
    54aa:       00 
    54ab:       48 c7 44 24 08 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x8(%rsp)
    54b2:       00 00 
    54b4:       c7 44 24 10 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x10(%rsp)
    54bb:       00 
;; Non buggy invocation here: both %rdi and %rsi loaded correctly.
    54bc:       e8 ef c3 ff ff          callq  18b0 <helper_function>
```

### Optimization Disabled

Now compiled with:
`g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -fPIC -g -O0  -MT file.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/file.Tpo -c -o file.o file.cpp`

```
0000000000008d27 <helper_function>:
;; Still the same parameters here, but it looks a little different.
... snip ...
    8d2b:       48 89 7d e8             mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
    8d2f:       48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
    8d33:       48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
    8d37:       0f b6 00                movzbl (%rax),%eax
    8d3a:       0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
    8d3d:       89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
    8d40:       8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
    8d43:       83 f8 17                cmp    $0x17,%eax
    8d46:       74 40                   je     8d88 <helper_function+0x61>
...

000000000000948a <buggy_invoker>:
    948a:       55                      push   %rbp
    948b:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    948e:       41 54                   push   %r12
    9490:       53                      push   %rbx
    9491:       48 81 ec c0 01 00 00    sub    $0x1c0,%rsp
    9498:       48 89 bd 38 fe ff ff    mov    %rdi,-0x1c8(%rbp)
    949f:       48 89 b5 30 fe ff ff    mov    %rsi,-0x1d0(%rbp)
    94a6:       48 c7 45 c0 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x40(%rbp)
    94ad:       00 
    94ae:       48 c7 45 c8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x38(%rbp)
    94b5:       00 
    94b6:       c7 45 d0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x30(%rbp)
    94bd:       48 8d 55 c0             lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rdx
    94c1:       48 8b 85 38 fe ff ff    mov    -0x1c8(%rbp),%rax
    94c8:       48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
    94cb:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
;; ***** NOT BUGGY HERE *****
;; Now, without optimization, both %rdi and %rsi loaded correctly.
    94ce:       e8 54 f8 ff ff          callq  8d27 <helper_function>

0000000000008eec <different_perfectly_fine_invoker>:
    8eec:       55                      push   %rbp
    8eed:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    8ef0:       48 83 ec 30             sub    $0x30,%rsp
    8ef4:       48 89 7d d8             mov    %rdi,-0x28(%rbp)
    8ef8:       48 c7 45 e0 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x20(%rbp)
    8eff:       00 
    8f00:       48 c7 45 e8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
    8f07:       00 
    8f08:       c7 45 f0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x10(%rbp)
    8f0f:       48 8d 55 e0             lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rdx
    8f13:       48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
    8f17:       48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
    8f1a:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
;; Another example of non-optimized call to that function.
    8f1d:       e8 05 fe ff ff          callq  8d27 <helper_function>
```

### The Original C++ Code

This is a sanitized version of the original C++. I've just changed some names
and removed irrelevant code. Forgive my paranoia, I just don't want to expose
too much code from unpublished and unreleased work :-).

```
static void helper_function(my_struct_t *e, int *outArr)
{
  unsigned char event_type = e->header.type;
  if (event_type == event_A || event_type == event_B) {
    outArr[0] = action_one;
  } else if (event_type == event_C) {
    outArr[0] = action_one;
    outArr[1] = action_two;
  } else if (...) { ... }
}

static void buggy_invoker(my_struct_t *e, predicate_t pred)
{
  // MAX_ACTIONS is #defined to 5
  int action_array[MAX_ACTIONS] = {0};
  helper_function(e, action_array);
  ...
}

static int has_any_actions(my_struct_t *e)
{
  int actions[MAX_ACTIONS] = {0};
  helper_function(e, actions);
  return actions[0] != 0;
}

// *** ENTRY POINT to this code is this function (note not static).
void perfectly_fine_invoker(my_struct_t e, predicate_t pred)
{
  memfence();
  if (has_any_actions(&e)) {
    buggy_invoker(&e, pred);
  }
  ...
}
```

If you think I've obfuscated or eliminiated too much, let me know. Users of
this code call 'perfectly_fine_invoker'. With optimization, g++ optimizes the
'has_any_actions' function away into a direct call to 'helper_function', which
you can see in the assembly.

### The Question

So, my question is, does it look like a buggy optimization to anyone else?

If it would be helpful, I could post a sanitized version of the original C++ code.

This is my first posting to Stack Overflow, so please let me know if I can do
anything to make the question clearer, or provide any additional information.

### The Answer

Edit (several days after the fact):

I accepted an answer below to my question -- it was not an optimization bug in g++, I was just looking at the assembly code wrong.

However, for whoever may be viewing this question in the future, I've found the answer.  I did some reading on undefined behavior in C ( http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213 and http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html ) and some of the descriptions of the compiler optimizing away functions with undefined behavior seemed eerily familiar.

I added some NULL-pointer checks to the function 'helper_function' and lo and behold... bug goes away. I should have had the NULL-pointer checks to begin with, but apparently not having them allowed g++ to do whatever it wanted (in my case, optimize away the call).

Hope this information helps someone down the road.

Comment: it would be helpful to see the original code.

Comment: Yes, we need to see the C++.  It's possible that g++ did something wrong, but it is rather more likely that your code triggers undefined behavior.

Comment: Your code is probably broken and invoking UB. Can't really help without seeing it... Always first assume that _you_ are wrong, not the industry-standard C++ compiler.

Comment: The assembly doesn't really tell us anything. It shows us what the code does, but not *why* it does that, or what it *should* do.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: But it's always so much easier to blame the compiler.

Comment: Original (sanitized) C++ coming right up, just give me a few minutes to put it together. Then I'll edit the original post.

Comment: Re "Code compiled with `g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -fPIC -g -O2 -MT file.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/file.Tpo -c -o file.o file.cpp`": Try adding `-Wall` to the list. Always use `-Wall`. In fact, there are some warnings that are not enabled by `-Wall`.

Comment: Post edited with C++ code. I hope I explained it enough to understand what's going on.

Comment: Can you try to boil the code down to the minimum required to show the issue, and include a main() function so we can run it easily ourselves?

Comment: "But where is %rdi populated?" : probably in the code that calls `buggy_invoker`. Since `e` is passed as parameter to it, `%rdi` likely already contains the right value, and it doesn't need to be explicitly set again inside `buggy_invoker`.

Comment: What is the ASSERT that is failing?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. I've accepted an answer, because what I thought was the problem (what I posted) turned out to be my own misunderstanding of the assembly. I'll open another question if/when I find out more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking at the wrong thing. I imagine the compiler notice that your function is short and doesn't touch the `%rdi` register so it just leaves it alone (you have the same variable as the first parameter, which I guess is what is placed in `%rdi`. See page 21 here http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)

If you look at the unoptimized version it saves the `%rdi` register on this line

```
9498:       48 89 bd 38 fe ff ff    mov    %rdi,-0x1c8(%rbp)
```

...and then later just before calling `helper_function` it moves the saved value into `%rax` that is moved into `%rdi`.

```
94c1:       48 8b 85 38 fe ff ff    mov    -0x1c8(%rbp),%rax
94c8:       48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
94cb:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
```

When optimizing it the compiler just get rid of all that moving back and forth.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that insight. I went back to look at the assembly again and the caller of 'buggy_invoker' was indeed setting %rdi. I'll accept this as the answer even though my bug is not solved because this does answer the question I asked :-).